# Calling a Python Script using SQL server agent - modules not found error

Tags: python

I have a python script that is calling the google sheets api.
The code works fine, no errors.

I put the code onto a server into a folder (C:\GoogleAPI\main.py)

I can run this using powershell and from the command prompt :
python.exe C:\googleapi\main.py (this works fine)

Now, problem is running under SQL server agent...

The error returned is :
from googleapiclient.discovery import build  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.

i used pip to install everything and all libraries are in the site-packages folder in :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\site-packages

When i run the SQL job, i am using a credential which is mapped to my user (also an admin on the server).

So, my question is, why will the sql agent not recognise the libraries when running using SQL Server agent????

system Path variable contains a link to C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\site-packages

i am very frustrated with this as i cannot find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Try running a script on the SQL Server Agent that *just* prints out what your `PYTHONPATH` is. I bet that it's not actually looking at your system path.

Comment: i created a system enviornment variable : PYTHONPATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\

correct?

Comment: ok i did this :

print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', ''))
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\

Comment: and still doesnt work

Comment: somebody must have come across this before!! ??

Comment: It might help to clean up your question formatting. I'm not super familiar with Python on windows, so I don't know how much help I can be, but this smells very deeply of Python not having access to the right environment. I'd look at the documentation on SQL Server Agent to see if they have directions on how to set up a virtual environment or access the system python environment.

Comment: ok, so i found something that helped with the problem.
restarting the SQL server agent FFS!!!

now another problem is that the process hangs when trying to connect to google when running using sql agent !

Answer (score 0):

OK, so, the "solution" here to get around the *modules not found* error is by restarting the SQL server agent !

Comment: i managed to *fix* the other issue also :)